# Dynamic label printing in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using dynamic label printing app and its working fine,(I am creating different labels for different customers) as [Dynamic label setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUWzB.png)

I created label for demooo-1,Company-3,Company-2 ..And I got [labels list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEkdq.png)

Its working fine , But I dont want the print option of Company-3 and Company-2, when I enter into demooo-2 record .... How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

create One Button in Your Form View

```
<record id="invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">   
    <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Invoice">
            <header>    
               <button name="invoice_print" string="Print" type="object" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('sent','=',True), ('state', '!=', 'open')]}" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
           </header>
           </form>
       </field>
   </field>
</record>
```

In you Python Logic file create one method like below

```
@api.multi
def invoice_print(self):
    """ Print the invoice and mark it as sent, so that we can see more
        easily the next step of the workflow
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    return self.env['report'].get_action(self, 'account.report_invoice')
```

create One Report.Xml like below

```
<template id="report_invoice">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <t t-call="moduleName.report_invoice_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
    </t>
</t>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you jainik, but I am not getting how to give the particular invoice ID of the record as the action of the Print Button in the form view,(here I am creating different dynamic reports for different records).Is there any possibility to give domain for report option to make invisible for certain records.

Comment: @Sai1919 Can you elaborate more with your issue ?

Comment: Are u making the domain on print options or more options menu ?

Comment: @ChaiTAnYa...I want to show only the respective print option for that particular record.If you observe this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/AEkdq.png it is the record of company3, for this record(company3) I dont want to show all the print options (as shown in image label of demooo1 and company-2), I need to show only the 'label of company3' option in More.